# The `cleanupOrphaned` doesn't exist in MongoDB 3.0.2?

Tags: mongodb

I deploy a sharded cluster with the MongoDB version of 3.0.2.
I check the MongoDB 3.0 manual and find the command `cleanupOrphaned`.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cleanupOrphaned/#log-files

When I type this command from a **mongos' admin database** with the follow format:
`db.runCommand({cleanupOrphaned:"mydb.mycol"})`
it returns:

> { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: cleanupOrphaned", "code" : 59 }

Does anybody know why this happens???

Comment: Hi... If you find my answer useful then you can either accept and/or vote for it.....

Answer (score 4):

Run cleanupOrphaned in the admin database directly on the mongod instance that is the primary replica set member of the shard. Do not run cleanupOrphaned on a mongos instance. It is given in the same link.